# Mac mini M1 npm error npm ERR! code 1 when perfoming npm ci

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, canvas

I try studying code for the first time.
I am testing by running HASH LIP ENGINE in Visual studio and It has an error like that.
I guess there is something with ARM chip and canvas libraries but don't know exactly how to fix it.
please help me.
Thank you a lot.

```
npm ERR! path /Users/0xdatlemon/Documents/NFT/source_2/hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/0xdatlemon/Documents/NFT/source_2/hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/0xdatlemon/Documents/NFT/source_2/hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@17.7.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/0xdatlemon/Documents/NFT/source_2/hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@17.7.2 (node-v102 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.7.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.7.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.2 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
...
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/0xdatlemon/Documents/NFT/source_2/hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/0xdatlemon/Documents/NFT/source_2/hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.7.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this on terminal `arch -arm64 brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

[Ref](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1733#issuecomment-808916786)

Comment: I tried and it show another error ```arch: Can't find brew in PATH```

Comment: I install Homebrew through this [link](https://soffes.blog/homebrew-on-apple-silicon).
and then use your construction, It's go through but got another issue